# How to run TestLink with XAMMP?

Tags: xampp, testlink

I have followed this guide and also some youtube tutorials but I'm receiving this error message in web browser:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Attempt to modify property "results" on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\cfg\const.inc.php:409 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\install\index.php(20): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\cfg\const.inc.php on line 409

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/testlink/testlink_installation.htm#

If is there any way to easy install please provide it.

My current version of XAMPP is 8.2.4-0 and TestLink is 1.9.0

Comment: I downgrade the version of XAMPP to 5.5.30 and it worked!

Comment: But now I'm having issues with MySQL or database connection :(